# elements over video in native full screen mode - SAFARI

Tags: css, video, safari, fullscreen

This bug is appearing only in Safari on Mac OS and only with the current set up in our application. Initially I though it was a `z-index` issue, since some elements disappeared after updating that value.

Although there's a last element that has no `z-index` value and it's always displayed on top of the full-screen video.

*--see screenshot below--*

[image]

I have tried removing all styling from the bar you see on the screen and it would still appear on top of the video.

*--see screenshot below--*

[image]

As you can see the elements within the bar are still visible.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on codepen.io or jsfiddle and nothing is currently available in Stackoverflow or GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

removing `will-change` property from the container solved the issue.

### DESCRIPTION

The problem that caused this issue was the property `will-change` set to one of the containers of this video element.

The structure of the application is quite complex so I am not going to post the whole code here. Although by moving around the video element in the inspector and testing the full-screen functionality every time, I narrow down the problem to one div container that had this property.

If you guys find out the exact reason why the default full-screen functionality of safari broke down because of the `will-change` property, post a comment or an answer since it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my application. Web elements were overlapping fullscreen videos. Only effected Safari on Mac OS. I also assumed it was a `z-index` issue specific to Safari and initially tried modifying `z-index` when fullscreen mode was detected.  Thanks to Guilio G.'s comment above the issue was resolved by removing the `-webkit-backdrop-filter:blur(3px);` of a parent `<div>`.

Like Guilio G., I don't yet know why, but this `-webkit` declaration was causing the issue and removing it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue was being caused by `isolation: isolate` on an ancestor element. Removing this property fixed the issue.

Hopefully Safari fixes this, since `isolation` is a wonderful property that solves a bunch of stacking context issues.